# Do I have to create a new type to define array of objects in GraphQL schemas?

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I’m trying to replicate a REST API that I’ve built in the past and one part that got me thinking was if one of my tables had an array of objects. So for example, I have a table called Profile and it contains arrays Experience and Education that would strictly be under Profile but has its own fields as well but not its own table.

While I was adding fields in GraphQL, I bumped into this not really having a solid solution other than to create new types and then associating them with relationships and then have a resolver or a front-end make sure a Profile is created first before the Experience/Education portion is. I’m not sure if it’s the right way to do it or if there is a better way to do it. Down below is a snippet of what I ended up using… looking at the admin page, there are created tables for Profile, Experience and Education which is expected. But is there a way to only have just Profile and accomplish something similar? Or is this more of a way of life with GraphQL?

```
type Profile {
    id: ID! @id
    handle: String!
    company: String
    website: String
    location: String
    status: String!
    githubUsername: String
    experience: [Experience!] @relation(link: INLINE)
    education: [Education!] @relation(link: INLINE)
}

type Experience {
  id: ID! @id
  title: String!
  company: String!
}

type Education {
  id: ID! @id
  title: String!
  company: String!
}
```

Comment: This question is really specific to Prisma. GraphQL itself doesn't care about the storage layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Prisma, you can use [embedded types](https://www.prisma.io/docs/1.34/datamodel-and-migrations/datamodel-MONGO-knun/#embedded-types). You would drop the `@relation` directive and add `@embedded` directives to the types you're embedding:

```
type Profile {
    id: ID! @id
    handle: String!
    company: String
    website: String
    location: String
    status: String!
    githubUsername: String
    experience: [Experience!]
    education: [Education!]
}

type Experience @embedded {
  title: String!
  company: String!
}

type Education @embedded {
  title: String!
  company: String!
}
```

However, this only possible if you're using MongoDB for your database and there's some specific limitations listed in the docs when using embedded types.

Comment: Oh, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!